# Arduino/Unity feed sharing over serial communication

Tags: unity-game-engine, image-processing, arduino, serial-communication

I'm trying to send my Unity camera feed/image to an Arduino. 
I have the communication down, however I can send big byte arrays consistently to the Arduino. Unity only allows for easy conversion of the Texturerender to be converted to a jpg or png byte array. These use too much memory for the Arduino.

I need a way to convert a Unity screen capture to a bitmap array, or is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Describe in more details what the problem is.

Comment: Generally, using compression you can make a JPG much smaller than a bitmap. I think what you want to do is scale the image down before sending it to the Arduino. I'm not sure what you're doing with the image once it gets onto the arduino, but I doubt you need the full resolution image.

Comment: Would Arduino be able to decompress the jpg file? Apparently I am just tasked to get the image to the Arduino, I don't actually know what the Arduino is doing with it on technical level (they have not responded to my request for info) but I do know the Arduino is displaying the image on a screen and overlaying AR hud elements. So I believe I need to have lossless file format

Comment: @cch Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get mentioned so I wasn't notified about your comment. Assuming you still need help with this, could you try scaling down the bitmap and sending it to the Arduino in a lossless format? I'm assuming the Arduino isn't using a very high-resolution display for the AR HUD. Otherwise, there exist JPEG and PNG decoding libraries for Arduino, which you could use to "decompress" the image data from your serial connection.

Comment: Also, you mentioned sending a texture to the Arduino. I'm assuming this texture is probably just words or numbers? You could probably just send the raw data over serial to the Arduino and generate the texture on the chip itself. If you need icons you can always flash those with the code and just use them when you create your bitmap for the AR library.